# How to get confidence intervals for ALL cases of an interaction in the Cox model? (ideally with R)

Tags: r, confidence-interval, survival, interaction, cox-model

My question is illustrated with the output of R, but the rule should be software-agnostic.

Let's assume I have this exemplary output of the coxph result in R:

```
> summary(fit)
Call:
coxph(formula = Surv(Day, Event) ~ A * B, data = .)

  n= 194, number of events= 35 

            coef exp(coef)  se(coef)      z Pr(>|z|)  
A       0.909135  2.482175  0.575975  1.578   0.1145  
BYes   -4.891318  0.007512  2.220001 -2.203   0.0276 *
A:BYes -1.865463  0.154824  0.752446 -2.479   0.0132 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

That's what I got from the Publish package run over the above output:

```
> publish(fit)
  Variable Units HazardRatio       CI.95  p-value 
  A: B(No)              2.48 [0.80;7.68]   0.1145 
 A: B(Yes)              0.38 [0.15;0.99]   0.0482
```

I tried to reproduce the output:

A: B(No)

```
> round(exp(0.909135 + c(-1, 1) * qnorm(0.975)*0.575975), 2)
[1] 0.80 7.68
```

OK!

Now:
A: B(Yes)
I can derive the HR:

```
> exp(0.909135 - 1.865463)
[1] 0.3843015
```

but how to get the corresponding CI? Which terms should be combined? And how is the p-value for the second option derived?

Answer (score 2):

Should work for you perfectly. It will return the HR, CIs and the p-values for each combination.

```
Publish::publish(fit)
```

If you want to do this manually, you will have use to get the SDs from the fitted model, `summary(fit)$coefficients`, then use the `vcov(fit)` to get appropriate covariance (matching your x and y terms you want to combine) and finally sum both components up: `SD_x^2 + SD_y^2 + 2*cov(x,y)` and then take the square root from the sum - and you have the requested SE.